# Is there good software for measuring vowel formants?

Tags: vowels, software, formants

I am trying to learn more about how people *actually* speak English, as opposed to the traditional phonetic transcriptions (they may have once been accurate, but come on, there's no way the vowel in "and" is actually [æ]), and while I have found some resources, I don't know of a good way to measure the formants of a vowel. Is there any software that can plot vowel and diphthong formants on a graph? (Chrome OS, as per usual.)

Comment: Does Praat not offer the service you’re looking for?

Comment: Seems like it does, but I don't have Linux, nor the ability to install it.

Comment: Which variety of English are you interested in? In SAE (Standard Australian English) 'and' is pronounced with the TRAP vowel, ie [æ], in slow careful speech (it varies greatly in natural speech).

Comment: @nearsighted Why would that matter? Praat is available for Windows, Mac, Linux, Chromebook, Raspberry Pi (!), and even (though less stably) for FreeBSD, SGI, Solaris and HPUX. You can download installers that will work for probably 99.9% of normal home and office computers, and even on the off chance that your system is not supported, you can download the source code and compile it yourself.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut I'm interested in natural speech, not slow careful speech.

Comment: And @JanusBahsJacquet, I use my main computer at school, and Linux is permanently turned off. I can try to get it on a home computer, though. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I missed the bit at the end that specifies you use Chrome OS – more or less the only option that doesn’t have a straightforward, simple installer. I didn’t realise it was possible to permanently ‘turn off’ Linux on a Chromebook, by which I presume you mean that you’re somehow _prevented_ from ‘turning it on’. (If you’re only talking about natural, impromptu speech, _and_ isn’t a great example: it’s most likely to be either [ən] with a reduced schwa as its vowel, or just [n̩] with a syllabic nasal – or in the right context even just [n], a single, non-syllabic nasal with no vowel at all.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this actually works, but [it is reported](https://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/download_chrome.html) that on some devices, you just have to ["turn Linux on"](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/9145439?hl=en) since it is already installed. With that, you can install Praat.